# A subselect with join and 'where' statement on the joined table

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

There are two tables, `q_entries` (80 records) and related `q_entries_comments` (37 records).

When I do a join:

```
select q_entries.*,q_entries_comments.comment  
from q_entries 
left join q_entries_comments 
on q_entries_comments.entry_id=q_entries.id
```

I get 109 records.

Now, I want to limit the result to only 10 entries, first I do this:

```
select q_entries.*,q_entries_comments.comment  
from q_entries 
left join q_entries_comments 
on q_entries_comments.entry_id=q_entries.id 
limit 0,10
```

but that isn't what I want - in the result set there is one repeating entry with id=1, and 10 comments attached to this one 'entry'.

What I want, is to get 10 different entries, and as many comments per entry as there really are, so I do this:

```
select q_entries.*,q_entries_comments.comment  
from (select * from q_entries limit 0,10) as q_entries
left join q_entries_comments 
on q_entries_comments.entry_id=q_entries.id
```

And now I get what I want, that is 37 records (there are so many comments to the first 10 'entries'), but only 10 first 'entries'.

The problem arises when I add a `where` statement to the related table, like this:

```
select q_entries.*,q_entries_comments.comment  
from (select * from q_entries limit 0,10) as q_entries
left join q_entries_comments 
on q_entries_comments.entry_id=q_entries.id 
where q_entries_comments.comment like '%b%'
```

It obviously shows me too few 'entries', because it searches for '%b%' only in the comments attached to the first 10 'entries'. What I really want is to always get 10 'entries' and all the comments attached to them.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the WHERE clause in second inner query, like this:

```
select q_entries.*,q_entries_comments.comment  
from (select * from q_entries limit 0,10) as q_entries
left join (select * from q_entries_comments where q_entries_comments.comment like '%b%') as q_entries_comments 
on q_entries_comments.entry_id=q_entries.id
```